# Child of a parent of $(this) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, selector

i have the following html:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="imgtab" src="http://cloudsmaker.com/hipsterwall/img/salto-al-norte.jpg">
    <p class="textab">Paragraph Text</p>
</div>
```

with the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Initial Conditions
    $(".container > img").width("200px");
    $(".container > img").height("116px");
    $(".container > p").hide();

    //ON CLICK
    $(".container > img").toggle(function () { //fired the first time
        $(this).animate({
            width: "400px",
            height: "232px"
        });
        //$(**selectorneeded**).show();//This is where i need to show the text
    }, function () { // fired the second time 
        $(this).animate({
            width: "200px",
            height: "116px"
        });
        //$(**selectorneeded**).hide();//This is where i need to hide the text again
    });

});
```

The idea is a user clicks on the image, which expands from a 200x116px to 400x232px and then a block of text appears below the enlarged image. The text then disappears when the image is clicked again and the image reverts back to the smaller state.

I need to be able to refer to the text within the div to be able to hide it and show it.

I will be using more than one of these images on the same pages so i need to be able to use the `this`selector to refer to the text under the image that has been clicked and not the text under other images.

When i click on the image though the `this` selector becomes the image rather than the div so i cant refer to the

that is also a child of the div. What selector can i use to get around this?

Here is a jsfiddle if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/edddotcom/um5ct/

Comment: `$(this).sibling(".textab")`

Comment: [What do you call the other children of YOUR parent?](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).next(".textab").hide();
```

Comments have suggested `.siblings()`, but since you know that the text is immediately below the image, `.next()` seems more appropriate.